# C# Printing PDF to thermal printer (Star TSP100) produces an unclear/fuzzy receipt

Tags: c#, console-application, thermal-printer, receipt

I have a **C# .NET Framework Console App** that sends PDF documents to named printers.
I mainly print to an A4 printer & a thermal printer.

Here is a code snippet of the printing process:

```cs
// PdfiumViewer
var pdfViewer = new PdfViewer
{
    Document = PdfDocument.Load(filename)
};

// Create the printer settings for our printer
var printerSettings = new PrinterSettings
{
    PrinterName = printer,
    Copies = (short)1,
};

// Create our page settings with the paper size as the document size.
var pageSettings = new PageSettings(printerSettings)
{
    Margins = new Margins(0, 0, 0, 0), // No margins
    Color = false,
    PaperSize = new PaperSize("Custom PDF Size", pdfViewer.Document.PageSizes[0].Width, pdfViewer.Document.PageSizes[0].Height)
};

// Proceed to print
// Now print the PDF document
using (var document = PdfDocument.Load(filename))
{
    using (var printDocument = document.CreatePrintDocument())
    {
        printDocument.PrinterSettings = printerSettings;
        printDocument.DefaultPageSettings = pageSettings;
        printDocument.PrintController = new StandardPrintController();
        
        // Print the document
        printDocument.Print();
    }
}
```

I only print single page documents. Printing to the A4 Printer works just fine.
Printing to the Thermal Printer (Star TSP100) always produces an unclear/fuzzy receipt. You can see the difference between the documents & printout below.

[Unclear/Fuzzy Printout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LEPWf.png) |
[PDF Document](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ekSbc.png)

The page size of the PDF document is 3.78 x 7.92 inches.

Printing the same PDF to the A4 Printer produces a very clear document.

I just wanted to know why is the receipt unclear. Are there any possible fixes?

I tried converting the PDF to a bitmap for the receipt and then printing - The results were worse. The output was more unclear

[BMP Conversion output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AzUZb.png)

Comment: That's about as clear of a receipt as I've ever seen from a retailer lol. I think you're just 'spoiled' because you're used to the A4 printer being a better printing experience than a thermal one? You could try creating the PDF at a smaller size than the dimensions and see if any compressing/stretching is being done by the printer.

Comment: It kind of look like some scaling issue, like the image being downscaled using 'nearest neighbor'. But it could also just be a crappy thermal printer. Does the result look good if you print some other way?

Comment: Have you ever checked the actual number of dots on each paper? Most thermal printers are 203dpi and probably use 80mm paper, but the number of horizontal dots is approximately 576 dots.
This is far below the resolution supported by A4 sheet document printers. First, create PDF data with 576 dots horizontally, and print it on a thermal printer using dot-by-dot without scaling.

Answer (score -2):

Please verify Your printer settings. You should have similar window in Your printer's settings.
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kknMD.png)

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ewq0B.png)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I'll change the settings around and get back to this thread.